# Android - how to show mapFragment in tab action

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-maps-v2

I have tab activity and in the first tab i want to show a map fragment.
my problem is that i dont know how to do that.
I have map fragment that extends supportMapFragment, but still i have no idea how do i show that fragment in the tab.

**this is the main activity tab**

```
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // here i want to show the mapFragment. how should i do that?
                return new Maps();
            case 1:
                return new GroupsFragment();
            default:
                return new Fragment();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
**MapActivity**

```
  public class MapsActivity extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final int RC_LOCATION = 1;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    addMyLocation();

}

private boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    String[] permissions = new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    //If No Permission-> Request the permission and return false.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions, RC_LOCATION);
        return false;
    }
    return true;//return true if we have a permission
}

private void addMyLocation(){
    if (!checkLocationPermission())return;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
            if (mMap.getMyLocation()!=null) {
                Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + myLocation.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        addMyLocation();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post your Maps fragment

Comment: I have posted my mapActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                    }
                });

                return mapFragment;
            case 1:
                return new GroupsFragment();
            default:
                return new Fragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```